# How to send a code request in Python Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

**What I need**

I want to add the ability for users on website to add telegram phone numbers for Telethon

I want to do it the following way:

First page: site.com/add_phone/. Here the user enters the phone number and the script sends code request. `client.send_code_request(phone)`

Second page: site.com/add_phone_2/. Here the user enters the code and the script sings in with phone number and code. `client.sing_in(phone, code)`

**Problem**

I've tried to use several ways:

```
client.send_code_request(phone)

client.sing_in(phone, code)
```

But instead of sending code requests I've got "Please enter your phone (or bot token)" in terminal...

**Question**

How can I send the code request without Please enter your phone (or bot token) in my terminal?
So I can get the code and use client.sing_in(phone, code) to sing in

**Update**

I've found that `client.start(phone)` send the code without any input

Now I need to login. But when I try:

```
client.start(phone, code)
```

It shows me the input again:
"Please enter the code you received:"

Answer (score 4):

Do not call `start`.

You need to break this in two steps

###### 1. Generate OTP

```
client = TelegramClient(session_file_path, api_key, api_hash)
await client.connect()
result = await client.send_code_request('+91...your phone', force_sms=True)
phone_hash = result.phone_code_hash
```

You will need phone_code_hash also to login, so keep that somewhere like dump in database or something.

After that it will generate the otp and you need to verify it

###### 2. Verify OTP

```
client = TelegramClient(session_file_path, api_key, api_hash)
await client.connect()
await client.sign_in(
                '+91...your phone',
                code=otp,
                phone_code_hash=phone_hash,
            )
print(await client.get_me())
```

For both the steps above, `session_file_path` or `session_file` name should be same.